# MySQL Search Phrase or Part of the Phrase

Tags: php, mysql

I've built quick search engine to find products in a MySQL database but I have the following problem:

Let's take for example this product: "iPhone 6S (128GB) Neverlocked"

If I search for "iPhone 6", I will get the right result. If I search for "iPhone Neverlocked" it will not display me any results. No results will appear also if I do a "iPhone 128 6S".

The current code that I am using is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE lower(CONCAT(title, '', description)) LIKE lower('%$keywords%')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Y r u using lower function

Comment: Is using a FULLTEXT index an option so you can use MATCH?

Comment: You should as well make a suggestion in your question what you thought of could a fix be and why you're not able to turn it into code. That would make your question more clear. Otherwise it's just subjective that you wrote some code and it does not work so you've got the idea to ask others to write it for you. This is not of much use, especially not for future visitors of that question. Have you taken a search how other users are asking about how to do a word or keyword search with Mysql and PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use without lower function:

```
$query = "
SELECT *, LOWER(CONCAT_WS(title,description)) AS concatenated 
WHERE concatenated LIKE LOWER('%iPhone Mobiles Access%')";
```

And also check the difference:

```
$query = "
    SELECT *, LOWER(CONCAT_WS(title,description)) AS concatenated 
    WHERE concatenated LIKE LOWER('%iphone mobiles access%')";
```

You can also use this query by using

```
COLLATE UTF8_BIN
```

And I suggest to use mysqli_ because mysql_ is deprecated.

Comment: Using it without lower function will not display results if search for a simple "iphone" keywords and the title has "iPhone" in it.

Comment: Do u have any idea match against query

Comment: Just looking on the manual and I found it. I think MATCH is the solution, not CONCAT.

Comment: Yes but if u need just simple search than dont use match against its costly than to like any way answer updated plz try

Comment: There are three ways for full texg searching that I have used and so simple LIKE, MATCH AGAINST, SPHINX

Comment: here is what I get when I use your code: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE concatenated LIKE LOWER('%iphone neverlocked%')' at line 1

Comment: I suppose u already know about the single quote and double quote check you are using single quote string under the single quoted

Comment: Here is exactly what I use: $query = "SELECT *, LOWER(CONCAT_WS(title,description)) AS concatenated WHERE concatenated LIKE LOWER('%$keywords%')";

Comment: Some one mark your question as duplicate u can also chk thus

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$keywords = str_replace(" ","|", $keywords);
$query = "SELECT * FROM ads 
        WHERE CONCAT(title, '', description) REGEXP '$keywords'";
```

Comment: Tried this but when I searched for iPhone Neverlocked is showed no results and it should display the iPhone 6S (128GB) Neverlocked